# Change of QM Momentum operator under coordinate transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, operators, commutator

Can any one please let me know what is the general procedure to construct the momentum operator under some coordinate transformation? For example, I understand that if

$${\bf{r}}\rightarrow{\bf{r'}}=a{\bf{r}}$$

then the momentum operator will change as:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\bf{r}}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\bf{r}}}.$$

However, what if the factor $a$ itself if a function of ${\bf{r}}$. My understanding is that in such a case, the differential $d{\bf{r'}}$ may be written as $$d{\bf{r'}}=a\ d{\bf{r}}+{\bf{r}}\ da({\bf{r}}).$$
Then, is there any procedure to calculate how would the momentum operator transform?

Comment: Ok! So what? $\frac{\partial}{\partial r^{\prime}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial r^{\prime}}=\frac{1}{a} [1-r\frac{\partial a}{\partial r^{\prime}}]\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction you suggested. However, I guess something is missing: since by definition $a=a({\bf{r}})$, $\frac{\partial\ a({\bf{r}})}{\partial{\bf{r'}}}$ would lead to a term involving $\frac{\partial{\bf{r}}}{\partial{\bf{r'}}}$ and that should be accounted for in the coefficient of $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\bf{r}}}$ in your final expression. It is tricky as $\bf{r}$ is a vector there. I am sorry to have deleted this post before.